# Nexus OSS: publish to static mirror

Tags: maven, nexus

Do you know a way to configure Nexus OSS so that it publishes the artifact repository to a remote server in a form that can be statically served, e.g. by Apache Httpd? I'd like to use this static copy to serve only my own artifacts, so the nexus server could actively trigger an update in case there is something new published.
Technically, I think it should be possible to create the metadata for the repo and store them in a static file, but I'm not sure with that. Any hints appreciated.

If there is another repo manager to achieve that, it would be fine for me as well.

I clearly understand the advantages to use the repo manager directly, but due to IT rules I can run Nexus only internally and it would be necessary to have these artifacts available in a (private) repo copy on the Internet as well.

Answer (score 0):

A typical way to solve this IT requirement of only exposing known servers like Apache httpd is to setup Apache httpd as a reverse proxy as documented [here](http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/install-sect-proxy.html).

You can use that approach in a more restrictive way by only exposing a specific repository or better repository group (so you can combine snapshots and releases) and tying that together with a specific user or a specifically restricted setup of the anonymous user that is used by default when no credentials are passed through.

Also if you need more help feel free to contact us in the user mailinglist or on hipchat.